# Erro com "cordova run android"

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou recebendo um erro ao entrar o comando: "cordova run android"

OBS: Lembrando que já setei o caminho do sdk:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/giovanni/android/sdk/tools:/home/giovanni/android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/giovanni/android/sdk/build-tools:/home/giovanni/android/sdk/build-tools
```

ERRO:

```
giovanni@deathstar:~/Documentos/garconapp$ cordova run android
```

Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Answer (score 1):

Para corrigir este erro, basta instalar o android studio. E o mesmo sem encarrega de configurar essas variáveis de sistema.

Answer (score 0):

O Android Home deve ser a pasta raíz (`root folder`) do SDK.

Caso esteja usando o Windows, tente:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Leia mais clicando [aqui](http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/)

Se o erro persistir, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557504/ionic-android-build-error-failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable).

**EDIÇÃO:**
Para Linux, no seu caso, então:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-sdk-linux"
```

Comment: também é bom fazer download disto: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip e extrair para C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk só assim é que eu consegui resolver o meu problema

Answer (score 0):

Tenta editar o arquivo bashrc como sudo:

sudo vim ~/.bashrc

No fim do arquivo, coloca:

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/platform-tools/:/build-tools/

No meu caso, o arquivo com bin e bibliotecas do Android está na pasta do usuário, por isso eu uso $HOME como inicio do caminho até o arquivo, o seu pode ser diferente, só mudar o primeiro export pro seu ai.

Depois de salvar (:wq no vim), para aplicas as mudanças, executa:

source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer BUILD ANDROID

No cmd ->        endereço do seu projeto (D:\xampp\htdocs\TESTE5) >  cordova build android

Segue abaixo os passos que deve aparecer para dar build corretamente

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)

Welcome to Gradle 4.10.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Incremental Java compilation by default
- Periodic Gradle caches cleanup
- Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC6
- Nested included builds
- SNAPSHOT plugin versions in the `plugins {}` block
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/release-notes.html
  Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 18s
  1 actionable task: 1 executed
  Subproject Path: CordovaLib
  Subproject Path: app

---

•   E no meu computador:

•   Android Studio instalado e o JAVA instalado (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131)

•   Nas variáveis de ambiente:
•   ANDROID_HOME    ->     C:\Users\Android\Sdk  (endereço do seu sdk)
•   JAVA_HOME  ->  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
•   No path:      %ANDROID_HOME%\tools,   %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools,  %JAVA_HOME%\bin